# Dynamically Changing Excel Chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a range based table the has months April-March on row 1, then two metrics on rows 2&3 for those months. I have created a line chart based on the whole table and it works fine. But at the moment I only have data for April and May, so I see 2 points and then the rest of the year empty. I would rather the chart only show the months that have data for them, the month will always be sequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use named ranges to feed the chart and use formulas for the named ranges that include only the rows/columns with data.

One range to feed the X axis/Labels, and a range for each chart series.

This is all a bit much to explain in an answer here. Books and blog posts have been written about this and it can't all be explained with a few bullet point steps, especially if we can't see your data.

Try out a few things you can find about `dynamic charts using named ranges` and report back if you get stuck.